# Reduce bash environment variables size

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, parameter-passing

Let's say I have a program that takes a very large number of command line arguments or a very large single command line argument. Let's assume, that my application wants to accept a single command line argument as a string of 65536 symbols (64kB). As everybody knows there is a limit on what amount of bytes one can pass to process with a command line and environment variables.

And here is a little experiment:

```
$ set > t
$ ls -lF | grep "\<t\>"
-rw-r--r--  1 sergey sergey 118737 Oct 14 23:45 t
```

And this 118737 bytes is about 115kB. Header file `/usr/include/linux/limits.h` says that `ARG_MAX` is 131072 which is exactly 128kB.

Is there a way to reduce environment variables size of user bash session?

Comment: You may want to rethink your design if you are passing around more than 32kB in environment variables and/or arguments. Generally, this is better handled with file arguments.

Comment: As an aside, you want to avoid the useless `grep`; simply `ls -lF t`

Comment: How many variables are there in the output from `set`? Only three or four are absolutely necessary IIRC (`HOME`, `USER`, `PATH` -- any others?) though Bash will populate at least a dozen more, and X11, `ssh` etc will add theirs. But without seeing what's there we can only offer general guidance.

Comment: @nneonneo That may be very possible but is very unlikely to happen. The matter is that there will be tremendous number of such processes and keeping record of which process has what file will be very hard. But that may simplify things very much.

To be honest the command line argument is realy a list of some external devices' serials.

Comment: @tripleee In bash session there are not a lot of ordinary environment variables: some `BASH_*`, `HOME`, `LOGNAME`,`XDG_*`, etc. All of them will only consume about 3-4kB. Also, there are a lot of variables and functions that start with underline symbol. Some are for `_git_*`, others are for `_grub_*`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`set  | wc -c` (which is a much simpler way to count the size of all shell variables) is not relevant, since most of those variables are not exported and the limit applies only to exported variables and command line arguments.

Try `export | wc -c` to get a realistic view. On one shell session I happen to have open:

```
$ set | wc -c
241235
$ export | wc -c
4652
```

You can also get a variety of useful information from `xargs`:

```
$ xargs --show-limits </dev/null
Your environment variables take up 3730 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2091374
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2087644
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
```

Or a simpler report from `getconf`:

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

It is quite possible that your particular system allows more than `ARG_MAX` bytes.

Comment: Well, for `getconf ARG_MAX` I really get `2097152` (2Mb). But when I do `cat /proc/<PID>/cmdline | wc -c` I see only `4096` bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `export | wc -c` command is not enough if you want to use that route as an approximation. I use bash shell functions. A LOT of them. And I export them to be available in subshells. Those are only discovered with `export -f`. So in theory you really need the output of both.

However, looking at my machine:

```
$  export -p | wc && export -f | wc              
    147     479    9309
   6940   17029  150917

$  xargs --show-limits </dev/null                        
Your environment variables take up 121160 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 1973944
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 1852784
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
```

Perhaps the output of the `export` command gives a good look at the ratio between exported variables and functions, but it isn't reflective of the actual space used `(9309 + 150917 != 121160)`.

And that kind of makes sense. Here is the output of one random function in my environment, via `export -f`:

```
usage_init () 
{ 
    USAGE_OPT_P1="-p pathvar - The envvar to process. Default is";
    USAGE_OPT_P2="             PATH, if -p is not specified.";
    USAGE_OPT_P3="             The '-p' is optional, in which case";
    USAGE_OPT_P4F="             the first ARGUMENT is assumed to be";
    USAGE_OPT_P4O="             the ARGUMENT is assumed to be";
    USAGE_OPT_P5="             the pathvar.";
    USAGE_OPT_S="-s sep - Path element separator. Defaults to ':'.";
    USAGE_OPT_X="-x - Exports 'pathvar'.";
    USAGE_OPT_V="-v - Executes function 'listpath' after assignment.";
    USAGE_OPT_H="-h - Gives usage message.";
    USAGE_OPT_E="-e - 'pathspec' is interpreted as an egrep regexp.";
    USAGE_OPT_N="-n - Add index numbers to the results."
}
declare -fx usage_init
```

Here is the same function plucked out of `env`

```
BASH_FUNC_usage_init%%=() {  USAGE_OPT_P1="-p pathvar - The envvar to process. Default is";
 USAGE_OPT_P2="             PATH, if -p is not specified.";
 USAGE_OPT_P3="             The '-p' is optional, in which case";
 USAGE_OPT_P4F="             the first ARGUMENT is assumed to be";
 USAGE_OPT_P4O="             the ARGUMENT is assumed to be";
 USAGE_OPT_P5="             the pathvar.";
 USAGE_OPT_S="-s sep - Path element separator. Defaults to ':'.";
 USAGE_OPT_X="-x - Exports 'pathvar'.";
 USAGE_OPT_V="-v - Executes function 'listpath' after assignment.";
 USAGE_OPT_H="-h - Gives usage message.";
 USAGE_OPT_E="-e - 'pathspec' is interpreted as an egrep regexp.";
 USAGE_OPT_N="-n - Add index numbers to the results."
}
```

`export` (and I think `type`) appear to do some prettying for presentation which inflates the `wc -c` value.